# Google Map LatLngBounds for polygon.setPaths

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

Given I already have a polygon instance, and I am panning the map to bounds, I want to move the polygon to the centre of the map as well.

Is there a built-in way to convert bounds to polygon paths?

Ideally I want to be able to do something like:

```
polygon.setPaths(bounds.getBounds());
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  A [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#rectangles) will take a bounds object (which is rectangular) and display it on a map.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I already have a polygon instance, so I don't want to create a new instance

Comment: It might have been good to explain that in your question.  Your answer is the only way to do it (create a rectangular path for the polygon), with the caveat that the API is always changing, and that might become  available in the future (and you could create an enhancement request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just worked it out the plain old way:

```
var polygon_paths_from_bounds = function(bounds){
            var paths =new google.maps.MVCArray();
            var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
            var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
            var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
            path.push(ne);
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng()));
            path.push(sw);
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng()));
            paths.push(path);
            return paths;
        }
```